# Raspberry Pi Losing Mounted Drive After Reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi, mount, network-drive

Brand new to the world of Pi - like so new that I had never even touched one until three days ago, and know very little about Linux...  I have a Western Digital MyBook plugged directly into my router, and I've found I'm able to mount this as a drive with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs  -o user=yourusername,passwd=yourpasswd,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //mybookIP/public  /mnt/mybook
```

Unfortunately, it seems to drop this mount whenever I reboot.  Anyone have a suggestion on how to make this permanent?

Comment: Mounting is active for current session, it is not permanent. You have to add this in `/etc/init.d` or similar autorun list to be available always.

Comment: I believe you're supposed to add it to your fstab file, then it'll come up on reboot...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments here, this is what I did:

First, in Terminal I ran:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Once that was opened, I added the line:

```
//mbookIP/public /mnt/mybook cifs _netdev,username=yourusername,password=yourpasswd 0 0
```

Once I saved this I was able to reboot and the mounted drive was visible when it all loaded back up again.